# How to get target URL?

Tags: c#

I'm writing an application which extracts image files from .css.
First I scan the HTML file to extract all .css files:

In HTML I have something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="TemplatesFBL/Styles/screen.css" />
```

**www.mysite.com/Templates/Styles/screen.css** is my first target link.

Inside that file I may have something like this:

> background-image:url('../Images/CssImg/pageShadowSides.gif');

The question is, how can I combine **www.mysite.com/Templates/Styles** and **../Images/CssImg/pageShadowSides.gif** in order to get **www.mysite.com/Templates/Images/CssImg/pageShadowSite.gif**?

Can I use some built-in function or do I have to write my own?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Uri` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx).

Store a `Uri` for the base URL, then create a new `Uri` with a relative path:

```
var baseUri = new Uri("http://www.mysite.com/Templates/Styles/screen.css", UriKind.Absolute);
var fullUri = new Uri(baseUri, "../Images/CssImg/pageShadowSides.gif");
```

Note that the CSS filename should be included in the URL.
Since it doesn't end in a slash, the Uri parser will realize that it's a filename and behave correctly.